# Junit testing for base64 encoded string

Tags: java, regex, junit, base64, assert

I'm trying to read the contents of a PDF using Apache's PDFBox and encode it in base64 so I can stream it to elsewhere. To encode it I use the Apache commons Base64OutputStream class. Like so,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Base64OutputStream base64Output = new Base64OutputStream(byteOutput);
List pages = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
Iterator iter = pages.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  PDPage page = (PDPage) iter.next();
  PDResources resources = page.getResources();
  Map<String, PDXObjectImage> pageImages = resources.getImages();
  if (pageImages != null) {
    Iterator imageIter = pageImages.keySet().iterator();
    while (imageIter.hasNext()) {
      String key = (String) imageIter.next();
      PDXObjectImage image = (PDXObjectImage) pageImages
          .get(key);
      image.write2OutputStream(base64Output);
    }
  }
}
String base64 = new String(byteOutput.toByteArray());
```

It seems to be encoding it but I need to verify it by writing a junit test to validate the base64 string. The following doesnt seem to pass it. Any thoughts ?

```
assertTrue(content
        .matches("^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$"));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using apache common's "assertTrue(Base64.isBase64(content));" seems to work just fine. Can someone please shed some light as to why the regex is not working ?

Comment: That exact regex works for me, I tried making a little java stub to test it. It compiles and runs successfully in both Java 6 and Java 7.

https://gist.github.com/melwil/5508003

Comment: Maybe you encountered line breaks? Or missing padding with `=`? Possibly `+` might be translated to space in HTTP transport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `Base64OutputStream` is using CHUNK_SIZE = 76, and CHUNK_SEPARATOR = {'\r', '\n'}.
Regular expression you are using to test if given string is a BASE64 encoded doesn't account for that.

Regular expression to match chunked BASE64 (with given chunk size 64 and separator \r\n) string could look like this:

```
"^(([\\w+/]{4}){19}\r\n)*(([\\w+/]{4})*([\\w+/]{4}|[\\w+/]{3}=|[\\w+/]{2}==))$"
```